# How to efficiently compute similarity between documents in a stream of documents

Tags: node.js, stream, nlp, cosine-similarity, term-document-matrix

I gather Text documents (in Node.js) where one document `i` is represented as a list of words.
What is an efficient way to compute the similarity between these documents, taking into account that new documents are coming as a sort of stream of documents?

I currently use cos-similarity on the Normalized Frequency of the words within each document. I don't use the TF-IDF (Term frequency, Inverse document frequency) because of the scalability issue since I get more and more documents.

### Initially

My first version was to start with the currently available documents, compute a big Term-Document matrix `A`, and then compute `S = A^T x A` so that `S(i, j)` is (after normalization by both `norm(doc(i))` and `norm(doc(j))`) the cos-similarity between documents `i` and `j` whose word frequencies are respectively `doc(i)` and `doc(j)`.

### For new documents

What do I do when I get a new document `doc(k)`? Well, I have to compute the similarity of this document with all the previous ones, which doesn't require to build a whole matrix. I can just take the inner-product of `doc(k) dot doc(j)` for all previous `j`, and that result in `S(k, j)`, which is great.

### The troubles

1. Computing `S` in Node.js is really long. Way too long in fact! So I decided to create a C++ module which would do the whole thing much faster. And it does! But I cannot wait for it, I should be able to use intermediate results. And what I mean by "not wait for it" is both

   a. wait for the computation to be done, but also
   b. wait for the matrix `A` to be built (it's a big one).
2. Computing new `S(k, j)` can take advantage of the fact that documents have way less words than the set of all the given words (which I use to build the whole matrix `A`). Thus, it looks faster to do it in Node.js, avoiding a lot of extra-resource to be taken to access the data.

But is there any better way to do that?

**Note** : the reason I started computing `S` is that I can easily build `A` in Node.js where I have access to all the data, and then do the matrix multiplication in C++ and get it back in Node.js, which speeds the whole thing a lot. But now that computing `S` gets impracticable, it looks useless.

**Note 2** : yep, I don't have to compute the whole `S`, I can just compute the upper-right elements (or the lower-left ones), but that's not the issue. The time computation issue is not of that order.

Comment: Have you had a look at random projection lsh?

Answer (score -1):

If one has to solve it today, just use pre-trained word vectors from fasttext or word2vec